# Why are my autocomplete options are not formatted?

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete, formatting

I recently have been using another company's (Markit's) API to pull stock names from their database in an autocomplete format, but my given "list" is being formatted in bullet points instead of a nice looking text box.

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response) {
      $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){ 

        },
        url: "http://dev.markitondemand.com/api/Lookup/jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
          input: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response( $.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.Name + " (" +item.Exchange+ ")",
              value: item.Symbol
            }
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 1,
  });
```

Is there a problem with this javascript/jquery or does it come down to a styling error?

My HTML code for the input text field is as so...

```
<input id="symbolsearch" type="text" placeholder="Enter company name or symbol" autocomplete="off" ></input>
```

Comment: forgot to include the JQuery UI formatting CSS that allows me to format my JQuery widgets with a downloaded theme package!

Dumb mistake on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you may find a solution for this problem. You have to take off the list off from your autocomplete. To do that put following statement to your CSS

ul.ui-autocomplete {

```
list-style: none;
```

}

Regards Pubudu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just found the answer: I was missing the reference to the jquery-ui.css in my page header. To your `<head></head>` block, just add this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
```

Reload the page from cache (ctrl-F5 on Windows, cmd-F5 on Mac) & see if you see the improved results.